# export data into excel using BCP AND commandShell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I am selecting the data from view

I am Getting the error

```
usage: bcp [[db_name.]owner.]table_name[:slice_num] [partition pname] {in | out} [filename]
[-m maxerrors] [-f formatfile] [-e errfile] [-d discardfileprefix] 
[-F firstrow] [-L lastrow] [-b batchsize]
[-n] [-c] [-t field_terminator] [-r row_terminator]
[-U username] [-P password] [-I interfaces_file] [-S server]
[-a display_charset] [-z language] [-v]
[-i input_file] [-o output_file] 
[-A packet size] [-J client character set] 
[-T text or image size] [-E] [-g id_start_value] [-N] [-W] [-X]
[-M LabelName LabelValue] [-labeled]
[-K keytab_file] [-R remote_server_principal] [-C]
[-V [security_options]] [-Z security_mechanism] [-Q] [-Y]
[-y sybase directory] [-x trusted.txt_file]
[--clienterr errfile] [--maxconn maximum_connections]
[--show-fi] [--hide-vcc]
[--colpasswd [[[db_name.[owner].]table_name.]column_name [password]]]
[--keypasswd [[db_name.[owner].]key_name [password]]]
[--initstring ASE initialization string] [--quoted-fname]
```

NULL

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

Select @sql=  'bcp "Select * from eBenefitSync_GUI_PH.dbo.Disp_View" out D:\Contacts.txt -c -T ' +'-s ' +@@servername+'\'+@@servicename
--EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @SQL
```

Comment: Please print `@sql` and post it

Comment: Did you try with just `'-s ' + @@SERVERNAME`?

Comment: Yes, It is not working with it, but working with IP, don't know why(time out error), i used also servername\instancename as well

Comment: Are you going to post the `@SQL` contents or not?

Answer (score 0):

The usage tells you it expects a database.table syntax, not a SQL query. Try removing the select * from:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

Select @sql=  'bcp "eBenefitSync_GUI_PH.dbo.Disp_View" out D:\Contacts.txt -c -T ' +'-s ' +@@servername+'\'+@@servicename
--EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @SQL
```

Comment: I have a complex query on which i am using join on multiple table. can you pl suggest me how can i do?

Comment: Is that not what you're using your view for? (I'm assuming Disp_view is a view)

Answer (score 0):

To export a query with BCP, you need to use the [`queryout` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#qry_out) instead of the `out` parameter. The [`out` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#out) can only address a table or view directly, not a query.